# Difference between "started something for communicating" and "started something to communicate"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> I started this blog for communicating with other country's people.
>   I started this blog to communicate with other country's people.

Answer (score 1):

With some corrections...

> I started this blog **for communicating** with another country's people.

Here *for communicating* describes the purpose of the blog.

> I started this blog **to communicate** with another country's people.

Here *to communicate* describes the reason you started the blog.

I would say the second example is more natural, though both would be understood OK. Either may be better, depending on context.

Comment: Would it be possible for us to suggest rephrasing of the original sentences to add a much more descriptive way to say "another country's people" ? If so, then I would like to suggest the use of "People from other countries", "An international audience", "People from around the world", etc etc.